# Sorting a list by content and length of element

Tags: c#, .net, list, sorting

I am new to c# and am looking for a bit of help with a problem I have sorting a list by the length of an element within the list, I will try to explain using a simplified version.

I have an Object List for categories with the following format List:

```
category.Name;
category.Path;
```

When I extract the list of categories from the external database and import them into the List they come in in no particular order, for example:

```
Luxury Seats      /Base/Seats
Small Seats       /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats
Seats             /Base
Small Gloves      /Base/Gloves
Large Seats       /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats
Small Red Gloves  /Base/Gloves/Small Gloves
Gloves            /Base
Budget Seats      /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats/Small Seats
```

From the above youcan see that they are in no particular order and simply follow the order they were in in the database.
What I am trying to do is to organise them using both the name of the Path element and the length of the component parts of the path element.  I need to achieve the following format by re-organising the list:

```
Seats             /Base
Luxury Seats      /Base/Seats
Small Seats       /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats
Budget Seats      /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats/Small Seats
Large Seats       /Base/Seats/Luxury Seats
Gloves            /Base
Small Gloves      /Base/Gloves
Small Red Gloves  /Base/Gloves/Small Gloves
```

So the List is structured into a heirarchy based on the depth and category names of the Path component elements.

If anyone can help me out that would be really great.

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what logic you are using to determine the order in your desired result set? Specifically the `Small Seats, Budget Seats, Large Seats` sequence

Comment: Why don't you sort it in the database. It would be quicker

Comment: You have two categories with the same path; is that a mistake?

Comment: I don't understand why Small Seats, Budget Seats and Large Seats end up in that order...

Comment: I am sorting this using a heirarchical path so I can output a CSV file to import the categories to an e-commerce system using a pre-purchased module which requires the above format.

Comment: @southpoint, that does not explain the order that both Thomas and I have asked you about.

Comment: The way the sorting has to turn out is to follow a path through to its greatest depth, list all of the paths from the Base path through to the last as the importer just uses a heirarchical path import and looks for the next.  The reason that Large seats follows Budget seats is that it is not part of the Budget seats path but will work because when importing Budget Seats the path to Luxury seats has already been created - hope that makes sense.

Comment: So could you swap the position of `Large Seats` and `Budget Seats` and this would still work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming:

```
var list = new List<Category>();
```

You have only two options:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(c => c.Name) // Luxury Seats; Seates (L -> S)
                 .ThenBy(c => c.Path); // /Base; /Base/Seats (shorter -> longer)
```

or vice versa:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(c => c.Path) // /Base; /Base/Seats
                 .ThenBy(c => c.Name); // Luxury Seats; Seates
```

---

Also you can order by path deepness:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(c => c.Path.Split(new[] { '\' }).Length) // less slashes -> more slashes
                 .ThenBy(c => ...);
```

Comment: This would not work for his desired output of `Small Seats, Budget Seats, Large Seats` would it?

Comment: Could be.  I don't think the question is all that clear at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for comments! I think OP's goal is not achievable. But I posted some variants.

Comment: @abatishchev - thanks for the reply but I dont think that would do it.  I do not want to do any sorting by name, only path.  I may have to revisit the importer and see if I can re-program that to accept an alternative more sensible format.

Comment: @southpoint: See my latest edit. It sorts by path deepness. You can try to play up with this parameter.

Comment: He's not even sorting by depth though... I think he might want to display each category path based on the order of the root category (if that makes any sense).

Comment: I just looked through the code in the importer that I have to use and I can over-ride a method to enable the import to work by ascending length on the path element so @abatishchev your edit to the above has inspired me to look down that path - Many thanks to everyone for helping - I'm on the right track now.